# ssh key generation and copy ssh key to other machines

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am running the following script to generate and copy ssh key to other machines in my cluster for password-less ssh.

```
#!/bin/bash    
#create host and password file
echo enter host-name,password in "host pass" format:
read hopa
echo "$hopa"> /root/host1.txt
sed -i 's/,/\n/g' /root/host1.txt
# SSH Key
#echo -en "y" | ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
# Passwordless ssh
echo -en "y" | ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
    declare -A hp
    while IFS=' ' read -r host pass
do
        hp["$host"]="$pass"
    done < /root/host1.txt
   for host in "${!hp[@]}"
    do
        pass="${hp["$host"]}"
        sshpass -p "${pass[i]}" ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -f root@"${host[i]}" -p 22
    done
```

When prompted for hostnames and their passwords:
My input:

> cephadmin 1234,ceph2 1234,ceph3 1234,cephclient 1234

Output:

```
The key fingerprint is:
    SHA256://CzhoYLtmVVRWoJTKfTkJV9BQbeKypzGoXBLV62KKw root@cephadmin
    The key's randomart image is:
    +---[RSA 3072]----+
    |         o+o+==.o|
    |       . .oB.*. .|
    |        + * B .. |
    |     . . B =   . |
    |      o S + . .  |
    |     . . + . .   |
    |    E o *.=.     |
    |     . =.*o+o    |
    |      . oo .+o   |
    +----[SHA256]-----+
    /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_rsa.pub"
    
    Number of key(s) added: 1
    
    Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p '22' 'root@cephadmin'"
    and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
    
    /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_rsa.pub"
    
    Number of key(s) added: 1
    
    Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p '22' 'root@ceph2'"
    and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
    
    /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_rsa.pub"
    
    Number of key(s) added: 1
    
    Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p '22' 'root@ceph3'"
    and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
    
    /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_rsa.pub"
    
    Number of key(s) added: 1
    
    Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p '22' 'root@cephclient'"
    and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

When I try logging into cephclient machine with ssh cephclient I am being prompted for password

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh cephclient
    root@cephclient's password:
```

How can I make sure that my script works properly and I get the desired output, i.e. login to other machines without password?

Answer (score 0):

first time it will ask password. From Second time onwards it will not ask password.